# SP 2016 with SQL 2016 SP1

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, 2016

Has anyone tried to install  SP2016 with SQL 2016 SP? 
I checked https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx and I know it's supported with SQL 2016 RTM.

My questions are

Is SQL 2016 SP1 support SP2016? 
What is the sql edition will be used standard or enterprise (farm has 2 DB Server)? and what's the difference between both from license and capability view.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technet says `*Minimum* requirements for a database server in a farm`. So any newer ServicePack of SQL Server 2016 is supported (including SP1).

Your second question is not really clear to me. Please specify your question if the following answer does not match your question:
During Installation of SQL Server 2016 you have to enter a license key. This decides about the installed edition of SQL-Server. SharePoint can be installed on both Standard and Enterprise-Edition. Enterprise-Edition is only a requirement for some BI-Features. You also might need an Enterprise-license for database High-Availability (as you mentioned "2 DB Server").

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2016 SP1 is fully supported for the SharePoint 2016.

SQL enterprise come with all features as standard only subset of it. For SharePoint, I would go for the SQL Enterprise edition, as this will give us full functionality of Always-On .

Check the below blog for more about SQL feature comparison.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Does SQL 2016 SP1 support SP2016?**

Yes, it's supported.

> For more details, please check
>
> - **[Supported SQL Server Version for SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016/)**
> - **[Supported SQL Server Versions for SharePoint 2019](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-best-practices-sharepoint/)**

---

**What is the SQL edition will be used standard or enterprise?**

It's recommended to use Enterprise edition especially if you will configure `Always on availability group`.

Regarding Pricing, it's known the Enterprise is so expensive than standard as shown below

[image]

> For more details, please check **[SQL Server Edition for SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016/#sql-server-edition-for-sharepoint-2016)**